# Is it possible to convert dynamic web project to Maven one with no changes to folder structure?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

Is it possible to create/convert a dynamic web project to Maven one without changing the existing folder structure, expect to have `pom.xml` created automatically and be able to run the project as a Maven project?

Comment: It is possible to configure your pom.xml to conform to Eclipse's default project structure but I am not aware of a tool that will read Eclipse's metadata and do it for you. As [carlspring suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15361534/304) it would be better to use Maven's structure; [M2E](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) will create this for you.

Comment: when  i try and convert it to maven project(right click on project -> Configure -> Convert To maven project), neither does it change the folder structure nor does it add the dependencies from my lib folder.

Comment: when  i try and convert it to maven project(right click on project -> Configure -> Convert To maven project), neither does it change the folder structure nor does it add the dependencies from my lib folder.

Comment: It throws me Exception :

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.0: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: the eclipse is not able to create maven-archtype-webapp, but the same can be created through command prompt..what mi8 b the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "dynamic", but I'm quite sure you'll have to change your directory structure by the sound of you. Maven is based on the "convention over configuration" principle which means you are supposed to set things up like it expects them to be, in order for you not to have a hard time dealing with configuring standard things. Unless you provide more details, my answer cannot be of more use.

Comment: FYI: _Dynamic Web Project_ is what Eclipse calls WAR projects.

Comment: i have a java dynamic web project in eclipse. I need a pom.xml(maven uses). i tried to use m2e plugin, but it creates a pom.xml without dependencies.

Comment: @McDowell: Thanks for clearing that out -- I only use IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to a project , after you use the default options to configure it to maven , in your pom.xml configure your repositories and dependencies . After this delete the locally referenced jars used in the EE project ( because your POM picks these up from the maven Repo's) . change  your folder structure to the maven

```
src/main/java - contains your production Java code

src/main/resources - contains your production classpath resources (e.g. Spring contexts)

src/main/webapp - (contains WEB-INF/web.xml but no lib folder)

src/test/java - contains your test Java code

src/test/resources - contains your test resources (e.g. example XML feeds for web service testing etc)
```

you can now set goals to generate your war etc .

Answer (score -2):

Judging by the screencast I've just quite recently watched it should be doable.

Have a look yourself - [Using Maven Integration Tools in IBM Rational Application Developer, Part 2](http://youtu.be/TpKrF1dHtvM).